# Type Mismatch on Range For Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to rebuild a worksheet we use daily and in the process make it faster.  I've been working with ranges now and trying to incorporate those but ran into a problem when trying to use `UsedRange` to get the last row for the range than finding it.

My code:

```
Sub RebuildAllFormat()

Dim SheetRNG As Range, RowDelete As Range, SOSheet As Worksheet

Set SOSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name)

Set SheetRNG = SOSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1)   

For Each cell In SheetRNG
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        Cells(cell.Row, "P").Cut Cells(cell.Row - 1, "P")
                If Not RowDelete Is Nothing Then
                    Set RowDelete = Union(RowDelete, cell)
                Else
                    Set RowDelete = cell
                End If
    End If
Next cell

RowDelete.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

The above code gives me the "Type Mismatch" error on `If cell.Value = "" Then` and it appears that the For loop no longer runs through each cell even though I get the expected value from `Debug.Print SheetRNG.Address` which is $A$1:$A$1736.

If I replace `Set SheetRNG = SOSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1)` with

```
lastrow = SOSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Set SheetRNG = SOSheet.Range(SOSheet.Range("A1"), SOSheet.Cells(lastrow, "A"))
```

then the loop works as expected and I'm able to check values.  Running `Debug.Print SheetRNG.Address` after using the above also returns $A$1:$A$1736.

Am I missing something in the `UsedRange` code or is it not possible to use it that way?

Comment: Your comment "The above code gives me the "Type Mismatch" error on If cell.Value = "" Then and it appears that the For loop no longer runs through each cell" confuses me - how do you know it no longer runs through each cell if the first line gives an error?  Or is it a case of the line only gives an error sometimes (e.g. when one of the cells in column A has an error value of some sort)?  What is the value of `cell.Row` when it crashes?

Comment: Without anything in the For loop, it only runs once rather than the expected 1736 times.  If I place `cell.row` inside the loop, I get the expected row when it runs.  I forgot to place `Debug.Print` the first time hence the error.

Comment: If I print `cell.address` then I get $A$1:$A$1736 rather than 1 cell.

Comment: Change `For Each cell In SheetRNG` to `For Each cell In SheetRNG.Cells` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, and you yourself identified, the issue is that `For Each cell In SheetRNG` returns the whole ranhe to `cell`.

Use `For Each cell In SheetRNG.Cells` to get each cell individually.

There are other issues in the code as well. See below comments for reccomendations

```
Sub RebuildAllFormat()
    Dim SheetRNG As Range, RowDelete As Range, SOSheet As Worksheet
    Dim cell as Range '<~~ Dim all variables

    Set SOSheet = Sheet1 '<~~ Sheet1 is already a Worksheet reference

    Set SheetRNG = SOSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1) '<~~ May overstate the required range, but will work OK 

    For Each cell In SheetRNG.Cells
        If cell.Value = "" Then
            '~~ Qualify the Sheet reference, otherwise it refers to the active sheet
            With SOSheet 
                .Cells(cell.Row - 1, "P") = .Cells(cell.Row, "P") '<~~ faster than Cut/Paste
                If Not RowDelete Is Nothing Then
                    Set RowDelete = Union(RowDelete, cell)
                Else
                    Set RowDelete = cell
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next cell

    '~~ Avoid error if no blanks found
    If Not RowDelete Is Nothing Then
        RowDelete.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.Columns(1)` statement does not that work the way you have used it. For example:

```
Set SheetRNG = Range("A1:B19").Columns(1)
```

is not the same like:

```
Set SheetRNG = Range("A1:A19")
```

You can `.Resize()` this `.UsedRange`.

```
   Set SheetRNG = SOSheet.UsedRange.Resize(SOSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1)
```

Comment: Actually, `Range("A1:B19").Columns(1)` and `Range("A1:A19")` _are_ equivalent.  Properties like `Column` are _relative_ to the specified range object.

Comment: @chris neilsen, type `Set rng1 = Range("A1:B19").Columns(1)` and `Set rng2 = Range("A1:A19")` , and compare compare both in Locals Window.  They are similar, but different in some parameters.